# MVC3 REST Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest

I've created a basic MVC REST API to just get single Person from the datasource. It all works locally but not when I deploy it on to the server.

```
public JsonResult Get(int? id)
{
     if (id != null)
     {
           Person p = personBl.Get((int)id);
           return Json(p, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }

     return Json("");
}
```

My jquery call is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:50708/Persons/Get/',
            data: { id: 20 },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Name);
            }
        });
```

When I deploy it on to my windows 2003 server and call the Get function, it's always 404 (obviously there's no View attached as I just want the json).

I use a jsonp call as the server is on a different domain.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://192.168.1.187:1500/Persons/Get/',
            data: { id: 20 },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback'
        });

function jsonpCallback(data) {
    alert('callback');
}
```

Any idea why the above doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you are using JSONP. Your server still returns plain JSON:

```
return Json(p, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

which will be sent like this over the wire:

```
{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' }
```

A JSONP response would look like this:

```
callbackname({ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' })
```

It is not enough to only instruct the client about `jsonp` => the server needs to support it.

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-EnablingJSONPcallsonASPNETMVC.aspx) and use the `JsonpResult` illustrated there on the server.

Comment: Darin, I thought JsonP was just so I could get around calling the service on a different domain as I keep getting access denied. I didn't think that changing the json response was also required.

Comment: @fes, oh no, the server should absolutely support it. Otherwise what's the point of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) if clients could circumvent it so easily? The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) contains a good description.

Comment: thanks im reading through those links now. I will definitely need to implement this but the 404 that i'm getting just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I finally got rid of the 404 and I checked in fiddler and the json that came back was as you wrote above. Stupid question but once you get that back, how are you supposed to use it?

so if the jsonpCallback: 'callbackname'

I write a function callbackname(data) { alert('test'); } but it doesn't fire.

Comment: @fes, with jQuery you don't need to write a separate function called `callbackname`. You could use the anonymous `success` method. As far as the `jsonpCallback` parameter is concerned this is not the name of the function, it is the name of the query string parameter that your server expects and use to wrap the JSON in it. [The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) contains an example with Flickr which illustrates this in action.

Answer (score 0):

Is you're deployed site configured to use port 1500?  Is it under a virtual directory?  Somethings incorrect with `http://192.168.1.187:1500/Persons/Get/` I would guess.

Comment: I've just created it as a website under IIS6 using port 1500. Does it need to be under a virtual directory?

Comment: @fes: No, I just thought something might be off since you were getting the 404.

Comment: The framework was running 1.1?! so I put it on 4 and it finally got rid of the 404. I must have been blind or something and not noticed the ASP.NET version.

Comment: @fes: Good, glad you got it figured out.